# Laravel Change expired link token to reset password?

Tags: laravel, reset-password

I want to set expired linkto link 7 days when we sent link to reset password. I know, we can change it inside `config/auth.php`.

But, how can I change the expire link to 7 days? Please help me out!

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Replace `60` with `10080`

Answer (score 0):

`'expire'=> 60 *24 *7`

here `60` is minutes
`24` is hours
and `7` is days

Answer (score 0):

> By default, password reset tokens expire after one hour (value is in minutes). You may
> change this via the password reset expire option in your
> config/auth.php file.

See the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passwords#after-resetting-passwords